# Struts 1.3 Different behaviour on windows and linux

Tags: linux, tomcat, struts-1

I have a struts 1.3 application runnning on Apache Tomcat-8.0.3.Currently its hosted on windows server and we are planning to migrate it on linux centos 6.The project runs properly on windows server.When the same war file is deployed on linux it gives following error:

```
HTTP Status 500 - No action instance for path /home could be created
```

My index.jsp (welcome page) consists of this:

```
<%jsp:forward="home.do"%>
```

where my home.do redirects to HomeAction.
Edit:
    //Struts-config portion

```
<form-beans>
    <form-bean name="home" type="com.compname.appname.form.HomeForm"/>
</form-beans>

<global-forwards>
    <forward name="welcome"  path="/home.do"/>
</global-forwards>

<action-mappings>       
    <action path="/home" type="com.compname.appname.action.HomeAction" name="home" scope="request" input="/" validate="false">
    <forward name="success" path="home.jsp.tld"/>           
    </action>        
</action-mappings>

//Action classes
public class HomeAction extends BaseAction {

@Override
public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {        
    HomeForm frm = (HomeForm) form;
    HttpSession appSession = request.getSession();
    String SUCCESS = "success";
    //code here
    return mapping.findForward(SUCCESS);
    }

}

public class BaseAction extends org.apache.struts.action.Action {
//reusable variables and methods
}
```

Comment: For those who feel it should be HomeAction.do,I have done proper mapping in my struts-config file and it is already live on windows

Comment: you are using an old, beta version of Tomcat 8. Can you upgrade and try again? Latest 8.0.x is 8.0.36.

Comment: When it works differently on Linux an Windows I suspect a case problem in a filename: Linux is case sensitive for file names while Windows is not.

Answer (score 0):

File system in linux is different from that of windows, please try :

```
<%jsp:forward="/home.do"%>
```

or else, please post more information, such as your struts.xml or action class that can help find the issue.

Comment: Your solution did not work.I have added the extra information in my question above

Answer (score 0):

Well the culprit was something else. There was nothing to do with Java or Tomcat or even Struts version.To get screensize I had used 
`Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();` from java.awt package.This works fine on windows but was giving exception in linux.Further,I found that this is not the method I am supposed to use to get screen size on 'client' size so I removed it and then it worked fine.Thanks a lot to all helping hands.I hope my answer will help someone else.